# installing spree with rails 2.3.11

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, spree

I'm following the spree 'getting started' guide from here: http://spreecommerce.com/documentation/getting_started.html

I'm stuck at:

```
rails g spree:site
```

I'm using Rails 2.3.11 and not Rails 3. So I tried:

```
dan@bt:~/mystore$ script/generate spree:site
Couldn't find 'spree:site' generator
```

I couldn't find the guide for a Rails 2.3.x install..

Comment: Spree hasn't been on rails 2.X for a few versions now. I Think you will have to use spree legacy version 0.11 if you need to use rails 2.

Answer (score 0):

Spree gem 0.11-stable works against Rails 2.3.8. If you want to fix it to work against 2.3.11 you'll have to go through the code-base and manually update references for Rails 2.3.8 to 2.3.11.

Legacy documentation to Spree 0.11 is here:
http://guides.spreecommerce.com/legacy/0-11-x/index.html

There is a thread on the Spree Google Groups that discusses this:
http://groups.google.com/group/spree-user/browse_thread/thread/d0a22b82b2fb43ee

I highly recommend upgraded to the latest version of Spree (currently 1.0.0) as Spree-Conference was just announcing it. It has a rich feature-set, great bug fixing, and works against Rails 3.1.1.